# Prolog existence_error: not obvious

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I am pulling my hair out!  I have installed gprolog (1.4.4) on my Mac, and I am following (I think) the [instructions in the Gnu Prolog manual](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog007.html#sec8) to the letter, but the interactive environment is not remembering my definitions:

```
GNU Prolog 1.4.4 (64 bits)
Compiled Sep 26 2016, 00:06:17 with clang
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Daniel Diaz
| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
even(0).
even(s(s(X))) :- even(X).

user compiled, 3 lines read - 362 bytes written, 21729 ms

(2 ms) yes
| ?- even(X).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,even/1),top_level/0)
| ?-
```

As you can see from the interactive response, I enter Ctl-D after the second line of my knowledge base input (my only rule).  Gprolog says that it has compiled my three lines.  Why can't it recognize my query correctly?  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, if I enter "listing." after hitting Ctl-D, I get an empty line, followed by "yes"--showing that the environent does not have my definitions.

Comment: How did you installed GNU Prolog? Sounds like is not correctly installed or compiled.